# I need help with curve modelling

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, path

I'm modelling a decoration on a musical instrument (the reference photo in the background) and am out of ideas on how to fix a problem I ran into. I tried modelling the shape with curve - path option and got the basic curve:

[image]

But when I try to add depth, the curve twists, leaving me with this off looking shape:

[image]

I tried changing the radius, but the affected area creates even more distortion:

[image]

I already tried both 2D and 3D options and all curve defor options. I tried making this ornament with bezier curve as well, but it didnt work. I tried making on of the less sophisticated shapes (only small curvature), but the same problem occured at the end where the path curves the most. What am I doing wrong? Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You probably twisted your curve while creating it. Here's a proper workflow:

1. Position control points on vertical and horizontal parts of the curve:

[image]

2. Scale the control points so the bezier fits the reference (if you want to scale all points at once, press <kbd>.</kbd>, then <kbd>`I`</kbd> for *Individual Origins*):

[image]

3. For asymmetric points, you can move just one anchor, here I'm selecting two points and deselecting all but the anchors with <kbd>C</kbd>, then $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}0\color{#888}{█}$ *middle mouse button* for brush deselect:

[image]

4. You can notice since this segment is long, the limited resolution of the bezier is more visible. You could increase the resolution of the entire bezier, or just increase the resolution locally by subdividing this segment - this will also make it easier to fit the reference:

[image]

5. Add curve Bevel:

[image]

6. Use <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to scale the curve radius, or modify it in the <kbd>N</kbd> *Numbers Panel*:

[image]

7. Consider adding more control points, where the direction of the curve doesn't change, but the thickness does…