# How I can make a curvy flat plane for an ankor?

Tags: modeling

Ι am making an anchor ornament and I want to desighn the curvy part of it:
[image: A 3d model where an ankor is displayed. It is half made.]

But I have no idea on how to make this part. What I want is to extrude some sort of flat 3d object out of the background image:

[image: An ancor image where the author wants to make a 3d item out of it.]

Comment: You can either recreate your shape from scratch or use the image: convert it to svg, and convert your svg to a mesh in Blender

Answer (score 2):

Create two curves, the baseline and the profile.

**Baseline:**

Create a bezier circle, disable cyclic, notice how it changes the shape due to having auto handles, so after rotating it to be symmetric on $y$ axis, switch the handle types to FREE and only then delete the two excess vertices.

[image]

**Profile:**

Just duplicate the object and scale to $0$ on $y$ axis (will translate to 0 height on $z$ axis), then also scale it a little on $x$ axis (can adjust later). Notice how I switched the pivot to 3D cursor, to make the scaling also move it towards the origin (use <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>).

Now set the *Bevel* to this profile:

[image]

Subdivide (<kbd>F9</kbd> to adjust the number of cuts), scale, move, adjust curve radius (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> or numbers panel) to your (p)reference:

[image]

Also see:

[I need help with curve modelling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/291116/60486)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have a clean image of an icon with flat colors like this you can convert it into a .svg and import it into Blender as a curve and/or convert the curve to a mesh.
You can convert the image to an svg with inkscape, which is a free program. Here's a tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10m_2bPXa1s

Otherwise, if you want to trace this kind of detail there's many way to do it but I'd use a curve.

[image]

If you select the vertices and press V->Vector, you get the type with a straight line. Extrude them as if they vertices and place them on the sharp angles of the icon:
[image]

You can then select and move the handles of the vertices to make the lines curved:
[image]

When you have the outline done you can fill the curve by using those setting on the curve menu on the right and then transform it into a mesh with the Object drop down menu on the left top
[image]

Comment: Image originally is an .svg and I could not find a way to import it into blender.

Comment: Does the main menu *File > Import > Scalable Vector Graphics (*.svg)* not work for you? This import option is an add-on that should be enabled by default. You can check it, use the menu *Edit > User Preferences > Add-ons*, type in "svg" in the search bar to find the add-on. and make sure it's enabled.