# How to model this ellipse shape?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model the ellipse of this spaceship:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to do it... I tried to use two circular and use "brige edge loops" but I couldn't achive what I wanted, then I tried to scale a torus along the Y axis and still isn't good.

[image]

I'm having a hard time working with circular shapes, can someone help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: another option is to start with a curve circle and extrude it.

Comment: similar to this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/298605/107598

Answer (score 6):

Create a circle, extrude inwards:

[image]

Move the inner circle:

[image]

Remove the 2 faces in front:

[image]

Move some vertices to make the tip sharper, etc:

[image]

Mirror with a modifier, extrude up:

[image]

Etc:

[image]